# Counting users between two dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has just two fields - a date field and customer_id. I am looking to count the number of customer ids from each date field to current date. My query below is timing out  - seems very inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

```
select
  t.base_date,
  ( select 
      count(distinct customer_id) 
    from user_base as ub 
   where ub.base_date >= t.base_date 
    and  ub.base_date <= current_date
  ) as cts
from user_base as t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this gives you same results not tested but seems the way you extracted data was not the right way of doing:

```
select base_date, count(distinct customer_id) as cts

from user_base

where base_date between base_date AND current_date
```

Comment: worked beautifully. I can't believe I complicated such a simple query. Thank you.